# True or false. If A ∪ B = ∅ , then A = ∅ and B = ∅ .

Tags: elementary-set-theory

1. True or false. If A ∪ B = ∅ , then A = ∅ and B = ∅ .
2. True or false. If A ∩ B = ∅ , then A = ∅ or B = ∅ or both A and B are empty sets.
3. True or false. (A ∪ A^c)^c = ∅ .
4. True or false. If A ∈ B, then n(B) = n(A) + n(A^c ∩ B).

my work

1-TRUE. We see that the union of both sets presents an empty set. So this can happen only if A and B, both sets are empty sets.

2-FALSE. If the intersection of two states is an empty set, it does not mean that any of the sets is empty. It also means that there are no common elements in both A and B and these sets may not be empty.

3-TRUE. A^c means compliment of set A i.e. all elements leaving the elements of set A. So, the union of A and A^c will be U (universal set) i.e. all the elements are included.

4-TRUE. The n(A)+n(B) includes the number of elements common in both which is added twice. If we have 5 elements in set A and 4 elements in set B out of which 2 elements are common in both the sets, so, n(A)+n(B)=9

I need you confirm if my answers are correct or wrong

Comment: I guess in 4, it should have been $A\subset B$, not $A\in B$.

Comment: Your answers look correct to me.

Comment: Your answers are correct. But if you have to justify them you should justify TRUE statements generally and FALSE statements by giving a counter example.

Comment: 4 is TRUE but explanation is incorrect?  or at least confusing.  i don't really know what function n() is i assumed it was the size of the set.  if it is $A\subset B$ then any element in set $A$ must be in set $B$.

Answer (score 3):

I checked the first two and I have comments:

1. stating "this can happen only if A and B, both sets are empty
   sets'' is **repeating the claim** made in the question and is
   not a proof. A proof would be something like assuming that $A$ is
   not empty, then there is some $a\in A$ thus $a\in A\cup B$ and so
   $A\cup B\neq\emptyset$.
2. If a statement is false then you should demonstrate it which a
   **counter example** , $$A=\{1\},B=\{2\}$$ would be such an example.

Comment: Strictly speaking, since an universal set $U$ is assumed of which all sets are subsets, 2 is only false if $U$ has at least two elements.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, instead of restating the statement, you should notice that
$$A\subset (A\cup B) = \emptyset,\quad B\subset(A\cup B) = \emptyset,$$
and the subset of an empty set can only be ... an empty set.

For question 3, it would be better to use reason with a well-proven theorem: (I don't mean you are wrong though)

$$\left(A\cup A^c\right)^c = A^c\cap A = \emptyset$$

And this is a counter example why question 2 is false, if $A$ and $A^c$ are not empty.